# Why iOS build is not visible on the appstore connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I distribute my app at the app store connect but when I try to see the status of the build, this appear to me.
Can someone help me?

[AppStoreConnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmEPu.png)

Comment: You can check the Testflight Tab for more information about the build you uploaded. It takes some time for AppStore Connect to process the build and make it available for selection.

Comment: Also check your email. If there was a problem with your binary they will email you about it and delete it

Comment: Yes, they send me this morning an email that the app was builded, thank you!